# Showing something is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I asked a similar question earlier so I decided to rephrase as I was a little confused. I am trying to figure out if the quotient ring over the ideals below is an integral domain.

So for an integral domain we have to have a non zero commutative ring with no zero divisors ($f(x)g(x)=0$ to be a zero divisor, where $f(x),g(x)$ are non zero). I know that both of these are rings but I am trying so see if they each have zero divisors.

a) $\langle (x+1)(x+2)\rangle $

b) $\langle (x^3+x^2+x+2)\rangle $

For the first one if we expand we get $x^2+3x+2$, then trying $x=0,1,2$ we cannot multiply any of these subbed into our polynomial to make zero, hence there are no zero divisors hence it is an integral domain?

For the second one, again I can't find any $f(x), g(x)$ to make zero. So again I would say this is an integral domain. However I am unsure on both could anyone help me out?

Comment: For the first, you have two roots that are implicit in the factorization you're given — $x=-1\equiv 2$ and $x=-2\equiv 1$. Indeed, both of these satisfy $x^2(+3x)+2=0$, so I'm not sure why you say that there are no zero divisors there...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I understand sorry. For the next one it is irreducible so I guess there are no zero divisors?

Comment: If you can show that it's irreducible, then yes — but you do have to show that, and it's not always as simple as simply saying 'no value of $x$ evaluates to zero'. For instance, consider $\langle(x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x+1)\rangle$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$; no member of $\mathbb{F}_3$ is a zero of the polynomial, but that doesn't mean there is no zero divisor (as the polynomial is just $(x^2+x+2)^2$.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I understand thank you, so b) is in fact an integral domain but a) is not

Comment: One thing you should make clear: you say 'the quotient ring' but you haven't defined what you're quotienting by these ideals. I presume it's $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ but that should probably be made explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're looking at the quotient of the polynomial ring ${\mathbb F_3}[x]$ by a) the ideal $I = \langle (x+1)(x+2)\rangle$ and b) the ideal $I = \langle x^3 + x^2 + x + 2\rangle$.

So the question is if there are two polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in {\mathbb F}_3[x]$ that are non-zero modulo $I$, but whose product is $0$ modulo $I$.

For a), such polynomials exist by constuction: $f(x) = x+1$ and $g(x) = x+2$ will do.

For b), it takes a bit more work that such polynomials do not exist. It boils down to showing that $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2$ is irreducible modulo $I$. Because its degree is $3$ that boils down to showing that it has no roots in ${\mathbb F}_3$.

Comment: Thank you! So this means that only b) is an integral domain?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.